# windows 10 recovery disk on cd-rom doesn't boot

Tags: windows-10, recovery-disk

I've got a working Windows 10 64-bit desktop PC which I've created two recovery disks onto CD-ROM.

In both cases, the CD-ROM disks do not boot into a recovery environment on either the desktop or the laptop with a problem I have.

Each time, the Windows 10 logo will display, but nothing else happens.

Why isn't the Windows 10 recovery disk working when on CD-ROM?

The laptop is an Acer Travelmate 5740.

Comment: "Why isn't the Windows 10 recovery disk working when on CD-ROM?" - The disk your using either wasn't created in a way where its compatiable with UEFI mode, or it was, and you have legacy mode enabled, up to you to determine which one it is.

Comment: You must check if UEFI mode is disabled, most recent BIOS versions do not boot from other sources unless Legacy mode is enabled. UEFI works on the HDD or SDD source

Comment: @Ramhound I've checked BIOS, and can find no mention of UEFI mode. The laptop is an Acer Travelmate 5740.

Comment: @Steve Did you ever find an answer? I'm having the same problem. My working machine is UEFI and the broken one is Legacy BIOS. I've tried using Rufus to create a bootable USB drive and I've selected BIOS and "add extra fixes for old BIOSs" options and no dice. Ubuntu 18.04 will boot on the machine just fine. It's quite frustrating.